# Exclude one folder from Google Drive

Tags: c#, google-drive-api

I'm using **Google.Apis.Drive.v3** to extract files using the .NET SDK. Everything great and i'm getting all my Google Drive files.

Meanwhile I found out that all my google photos (hundreds fo GB are also being listed there).

Is there any way to get all/files and folders except that one? The folder is called "Google Photos".

```
FilesResource.ListRequest listRequest = googleDriveClient.Files.List();
listRequest.IncludeTeamDriveItems = true;
listRequest.SupportsTeamDrives = true;
listRequest.PageSize = 1000;
listRequest.Fields ="nextPageToken,files(id,modifiedTime,trashed,kind,name,size,md5Checksum)";

vr result = listRequest.Execute();
```

Comment: The API (https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list) doesn't seem to have any parameter to control this kind of thing :/

Comment: How about this workaround? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51065653/google-drive-api-v3-excluding-google-photos/51072624#51072624