# Google Drive API v3 excluding google photos

Tags: c#, google-drive-api

Is there anyway to hide the Google Photos folder and his child elements (folder and files) from the below call?

```
FilesResource.ListRequest listRequest = googleDriveClient.Files.List();
listRequest.IncludeTeamDriveItems = true;
listRequest.SupportsTeamDrives = true;
listRequest.PageSize = 1000;
listRequest.Fields = "nextPageToken,files(id,mimeType,modifiedTime,trashed,kind,name,size,md5Checksum,parents)";
result = listRequest.Execute();
```

Thanks

Comment: I'm really sorry I couldn't help. If there are some issues, can you tell me them? I would like to think of other workarounds.

Answer (score 1):

In the case of files in the folder of Google Photos, `space` has both "drive" and "photo". So even if `drive` is used to the query parameter of `spaces`, those files are retrieved.

Although I thought to use `Q` of drive.files.list, the folder of Google Photos cannot be directly excluded using `parents != '### folder ID of Google Photos ###'`.

I think that this situation might be a bug or the function for excluding Google Photos might be not implemented yet. So as a workaround at the current stage, how about excluding the folders under Google Photos? The flow is as follows.

1. Retrieve folder IDs under the folder of Google Photos.

   - There are the folders with the name of each year under the Google Photos.
   - The folder ID is `#####` of `https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/#####`.
2. For `Q` of drive.files.list, it uses `parents!='### folder ID1 ###' and parents!='### folder ID2 ###' and parents!='### folder ID3 ###' and ,,,`.

   - `listRequest.Q = "parents!='### folder ID1 ###' and parents!='### folder ID2 ###' and parents!='### folder ID3 ###' and ,,, and trashed=false"`
   - `trashed=false` means that the files in trash box are not retrieved.
   - There is the limitation for the length of endpoint because of GET method. I would like to expect that the official method is published before the length of endpoint is over the limitation.

#### Note :

- In this workaround, because the folders are excluded under the folder of "Google Photos", only the folder of "Google Photos" is retrieved. But the folders under "Google Photo" are NOT retrieved.

#### References :

- [drive.files.list](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list)
- [Search for Files](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/search-parameters)

Comment: Thanks for your proposal @Tanaike When you filter using ``parents!='## folder ID1 ###``you will only remove first level child of those. The Google Photos structure is : Google Photos > Year > Month > Files. So removing the years from the query (Assuming that the get request would work, I don't think so because a user can have dozes of years there, so the GET limit would be reached very soon) I would still get the files that are under the months folders.

Comment: @Hugo Hilário I'm sorry for the inconvenience. In my environment, I had confirmed that when top folder ID is excluded, the child folders are not retrieved. So I thought that this can be used for several years, until this bug is removed, and I proposed this method. But I couldn't confirm this method at other environments. From your comment, I could know this cannot be used for other environments. Thank you. And I would like to think of other methods. When I got it, I would like to report it. I'm sorry for my poor skill.

Comment: @Hugo Hilário I reported this situation as an issue. https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/111149036 I would like to also think of other workarounds until the issue is removed.

Comment: Well on my case it excludes only the first child folders. Please don't be sorry, you're taking your time to help and that is awesome. Actually, using your idea I did another approach that work as a temporary solution. I previously get all the child folders and files below the "Google Photos" folder recursively into a list, and then when cycling through all the files inside google drive (for the process I am doing), I will compare if the items parent and ids don't match those I have on that list. It's not pretty and efficient, but it's the only solution I found.

Comment: @Hugo Hilário Thank you for your additional information. I think that it is interesting idea. I was also looking for other workaround. By the way, I confirmed that when the folders just under the root folder in Google Drive cannot be excluded using 'q' of drive.files.list in Drive API. I think that if this issue is solved, your issue is also solved.

Comment: indeed. If that worked, the issue would be solved :)